# MySQL driver class not found, even when included in classpath

Tags: java, mysql, jar, classnotfoundexception

I have the following code:

### mypackage\Launcher.java:

```
package mypackage;

import mypackage.MainClass;

public class Launcher
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new MainClass(args);
    }
}
```

### mypackage\MainClass.java:

```
package mypackage;

import java.sql.*;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;

public class MainClass
{
    public MainClass(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.err.println("Error: unable to load sql driver class!");
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println("We got here... How???");
    }
}
```

The code compiles with no complaints using

```
javac -cp src;bin;lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar -sourcepath src -d bin src\mypackage\Launcher.java
jar cfe myjar.jar mypackage.Launcher .
```

but when running

```
java -cp .\mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar -jar myjar.jar
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: unable to load sql driver class!
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at mypackage.MainClass.<init>(MainClass.java:10)
        at mypackage.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:9)
```

I don't understand what I am missing here, and I have spent over 6 hours attempting to debug and searching for answers, but I have not found *anything* that has helped (pretty much everything I've found says "include the jarfile containing the class on the classpath – but I've very clearly done *just that*).

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[-jar option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html)

> ...
>   When you use this option, the JAR file **is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.**

The quickest way for you to launch it is to drop the `-jar` option, add your jar to the `-cp` list and use `mypackage.MainClass` as the last CLI argument. 
(just in case you are not aware) But only **after** you implement the `public static void main(String[] args)` method inside that class (no, the fact your class has a constructor doesn't matter)

The way to maintain the `-jar` launching style is to enumerate all you dependency jar files into the [`Class-Path` entry of the manifest.mf file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) of your main jar (the one also containing the `Main-Class` entry pointing to your launcher). 

<sup>Just be careful about the  locations you expect your dependencies relative to the location of your launcher jar.</sup>

Comment: Just noting that Launcher is the class that constructs the MainClass (other code happens in Launcher that defines the behavior of MainClass, but I was going for a SSCCE). +1 anyways. :)

Comment: Follow-up question: is there a way to somehow include the dependency on third-party jars in my jar without defining the classpath?

Comment: i.e. so I could just run the application as `java -jar myjar.jar` (or alternatively, just by double-clicking the jar)?

Comment: @radar33 " is there a way to somehow include the dependency on third-party jars in my jar without defining the classpath? " Updated my answer.

Comment: Awesome, that was just what I was looking for. Many thanks!